# Could not detect default resource locations for test class : class path resource does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins

I am having a little issue running maven build in jenkins. It's trying to run my integration test but, keep throwing this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@2d10dd87 declaringClass = 'com.xxxx.api.services.MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest', locations = '{}', classes = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader']
```

See link for full stack trace [link](http://pastie.org/9168654).

Answer (score 7):

The error is related to this part of the logs:

```
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.xxxx.api.services.MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest]: class path resource [com/xxxx/api/services/MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest-context.xml] does not exist
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.xxxx.api.services.MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest]: MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, inner classes annotated with @Configuration.
```

Basically, your test class doesn't have a configuration part (either xml or `@Configuration`) that it can use to build the application context.

See [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-xml) for test configuration with xml and [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig) for configuration with `@Configuration` annotation.

Comment: That is not true but, my fault of not showing my actual test, see link [link](http://pastie.org/9172200). I have a MessageServiceImplIntegrationTest-context.xml within the same location as the test as the spring doc said it would load (if one is not included in the "locations" of thee @ContextConfiguration) to load it from the classpath using the name of the test and appended with "-context.xml". When I run Maven Test from my eclipse, it's found and the test passes. When I deploy it to jenkins, it runs then it complains it can't find the file.

Comment: You haven't mentioned it works with Maven test. Hm, then there's an issue with Jenkins setup and probably with some classpath configuration, not with Spring.

Comment: I am thinking it's more likely classpath but, how could I be able to check..especially from Jenkins if it's possible or STS. Also what file jenkins or maven used to determine the classpath? I'm thinking this file is probably in my .gitIgnore and not submitted to jenkins.